# Only change div to li in Twig/Symfony2 when it's rendering via form_row

Tags: symfony, twig

In cookbook, what I understood, I can change markup for each type of field via form theming, but I would like to change only that `form_row` twig helper will give not `div` markup but `li` markup. Do you know maybe how to do it?

To make it clear. This is an example what is now for each row/field:

```
{{ form_row(form.name) }}
{# it generates #}
```

->

```
<div>
     <label for="cmailing_defaultbundle_clienttype_name" class="required">Name</label>
     <input type="text" id="cmailing_defaultbundle_clienttype_name" name="cmailing_defaultbundle_clienttype[name]" required="required" maxlength="50">
</div>
```

I would like to get:

```
<li>
     <label for="cmailing_defaultbundle_clienttype_name" class="required">Name</label>
     <input type="text" id="cmailing_defaultbundle_clienttype_name" name="cmailing_defaultbundle_clienttype[name]" required="required" maxlength="50">
</li>
```

Super cool it would be if helper `form_widget` generates markup like that `ul > li`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override those particular twig blocks you need. Here is an official [turotial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming-in-twig)

So, as long as you enable you custom theme you could do whatever you'd like with `form_widget` block (or any other).

See how they did it in official table-layout: [GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_table_layout.html.twig)

Hope this helps!